# Adding numbering when loading from XML files

Tags: c#, console, xelement

I have a `Student.xml` and `Lecturer.xml`. When the user creates a new student he has to enter the Name, Surname and then select a lecturer from a list loaded from my `Lecturer.xml`.

How I get the list of lectures:

> if (File.Exists("lecturer.xml"))
>
> {
>
> ```
>    XElement lecturelist = XElement.Load("lecturer.xml");
>    Console.WriteLine("Select a lecturer:");
>
>    foreach (var mainelement in lecturelist.Elements())
>        {
>            foreach (var subelement in mainelement.Elements())
>                {
>                    if (subelement.Name == "Name")
>                        Console.Write("Lecturer: {0}", subelement.Value);
>
>                    if (subelement.Name == "Surname")
>                        Console.Write(", {0}", subelement.Value);
>
>                    if (subelement.Name == "Specialisation")
>                        Console.Write(" Subject: {0} \n", subelement.Value);
>                }
>        }
>
>        Console.ReadLine();
> ```
>
> }
>
> else
>      {
>          Console.WriteLine("The lecturer.xml file is missing or corrupt...");
>
> ```
>    Console.ReadLine();
> ```
>
> }

Now this creates a list of lectures
Example:

> Lecturer: John, Kingsley Subject: Maths
>
> Lecturer: Ben, Hur Subject: English

How can I change my code so it displays:

> 1 - Lecturer: John, Kingsley Subject: Maths
>
> 2 - Lecturer: Ben, Hur Subject: English

So that the user can type 1 or 2 to select a lecturer?

Comment: Define an integer before the `foreach` loop, set its initial value to 1, then change `Console.Write("Lecturer: {0}", subelement.Value);` to `Console.Write("{0} - Lecturer: {1}", number, subelement.Value);`. Don't forget to increment the integer.

Comment: i assume that you want to pull this value into the application?

Comment: @ Malachi Yes the number must be used so I can save the lecturer to my student.xml file.

Comment: Then you need to add it to your lecturer file as an "id" for each lecturer.  You really don't want to just number them based on the order in the file because they might get re-ordered.  You can display a number to the user in the UI which is different from the teachers id but don't store the UI selection as the id.

Comment: @Kevin how would I add the ID to my lecturer.xml?

Comment: you need to make your application a little more complex than what you are thinking.

Comment: @Kevin So when I save my lecturer.xml I should add a `XElement("ID", idnr)`?

Comment: yes something like that.  Like @Malachi said xml is used for passing data generally but it can be used for data persistence (like a database) however you definitely need to add id's in order to make it maintainable.

Comment: did you figure out your issue?  if the answer is below please select it as an answer, or if you figured it out on your own, please post what solved this issue for you and select it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the variable so that if they don't pick one it doesn't error out.

```
Int intLecturerNum = 1;
```

then pull in their answer from the console.

```
intLecturerNum = Convert.ToInt(Console.Readline());
```

been a while since I had to do this, and I was doing it with a `Yes` or `No`  and there was a little bit more that I had to do with it so that I would get the right answer to my variable, but this is the general way that you pull in the variable.

```
XElement lecturelist = XElement.Load("lecturer.xml");
Console.WriteLine("Select a lecturer:");

String strProf;
Int i = 1;


foreach (var mainelement in lecturelist.Elements())
    {
        Console.Write(i.ToString() + " - ");
        foreach (var subelement in mainelement.Elements())
            {


                if (subelement.Name == "Name")
                {
                    Console.Write("Lecturer: {0}", subelement.Value);

                }
                if (subelement.Name == "Surname")
                    Console.Write(", {0}", subelement.Value);

                if (subelement.Name == "Specialisation")
                    Console.Write(" Subject: {0} \n", subelement.Value);

                i++;
            }
    }

\\ somewhere after this is where you read in the answer given by the user
```

you could Create a list and populate that list with Lecturers while you are printing them out.

or

you could create a class that will allow you to create Lecturer objects and give them a value.

or

...

Comment: Problem is how do I assign a number to each lecturer? Then know that when the user presses 1 that the lecturer he just selected is the one that got displayed?

Comment: When I do that the input is displayed as `1 - Lecturer: Ben, 2Hur 3Subject:` Then repeats for all lecturers

Comment: Although this displays a number next to each lecturer I still won't be able to Identify witch Lecturer to actually save to my students.xml I need to know that when I press 1 my students.xml adds the `<lecturer>John, Kingsley</lecturer>` to my student.xml

Comment: like I said in another comment on the question,  this is going to turn out to be more complex than what you are thinking of doing.  you have to set up class to create objects, or a list of arrays to hold the First and last name along with an ID Number. and then formulate a way to append the XML Element to the Student XML.  what I have given you is a way for a user to select an option, because that is what the question asked for.

Comment: XML is used to transfer Data back and forth. you transfer the data with the lecturers to the application and then you make the application do some work for you.  if I had all the pieces I could definitely write the code for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll do some more research and try something else. Thinking of using a `Dictionary<>` so I can add all the lecturer detail with a number into it.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea. I hope this helped you out, at least a little bit